# Https config dosn't work in zuul routing

Tags: https, routes, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a router application with zuul and many services that are run in the backend and requests from client are routed to their services by zuul.

Everything is working well over http but when I configure the router and all services to https the following error is raised:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <127.0.0.1> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:467) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:397) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
```

The zuul yml file :

```
zuul:
  ignoredPatterns: /reza,/we
  routes:
    trp:
      path: /micro1/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      url: https://127.0.0.1:8080/micro1
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
    port: 80
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
        key-store-password: password
        key-password: matin1234
```

And the yml file of one of those services:

```
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
    port: 8080
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
        key-store-password: password
        key-password: matin1234
```

First I want to know that the concept of https over zuul works properly and secondly I want to know how I fix my problem.

Note: I don't have Eureka server registration.

Comment: Does this error related to hostname verification?

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud are you using?

Comment: The version of it is 1.5.2

Comment: 1.5.2 is not a version.  Are you using Angel, Brixton, Camden, or Dalston?

Answer (score 4):

1. For consuming https service, you have to trust the certificate provided by the service if they are using self-signed certificate. For that you have to configure trust-store, not key-store
2. If the self-signed certificate DN and domain name of the service are not matching, you have to configure zuul to disable that validation - but please note that this is not recommended in production
   Configuration is given below:

   ```
   zuul.sslHostnameValidationEnabled=false
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to your certificates being self-signed with "**Subject name (DN)**" not matching 127.0.0.1. You have two options here:

- Create a certificate with DN=127.0.0.1
- [Disable host verification](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1057)

**UPDATE:**

Just noticed your question:

> I want to know that the concept of https over zuul

Usually, nobody supports HTTPS between zuul and the underlying microservices because:

- **It affects performance**. Imagine all your microservices use HTTPS for internal communication. HTTPS encryption, decryption, handshakes, etc. much more consumes resources comparing to plain HTTP communication.
- **Supporting HTTPS for all the microservices will make you cry**. In large systems where you have hundreds (or thousands of microservices) changing certificates because some of them are expired will be a headache.

A common use case is to have your API Gateway running over HTTPS. But communication from the gateway to the underlying services as well as intercommunication between microservices should be over HTTP. The thing is that anyway **you have to focus on secure networking for your microservices instead of secure communication between them**. You system under the gateway should use a private network where nobody should have an access to.

There might be a case where you must have HTTPS between microservices for one more layer of security, but it's uncommon and related mostly to Banking. On the other hand, you could add HTTPS to services with a very sensitive data while the rest of them can stay on HTTP. It's more a question of the requirements that you have.

Comment: Dn of router or Dn of service application must be created?

Comment: To fix the problem it should be service app I guess.

Comment: I have updated my answer with info regarding the conception of HTTPS, API Gateway and microservices. Hopefully, you'll find it helpful.

Comment: @dzatorsky: Suppose the API gateway is deployed over a public network, for an instance: Heroku. How would that interact with a service which is hosted on a private network? Where would the service registry need to hosted so that it can register services on the private network and can help API gateway to identify them?